# How to fix an 'UnboundLocalError' in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to  write a Discord Role Reaction Bot in Python.
But I have a `UnboundLocalError`on my variable `role_to_add`

I already tried to change the name of the variable.

Here is my code :

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    message_id = payload.message_id


    if message_id == 634732408016601186:

        if payload.emoji.name == ":white_check_mark:":
            role_to_add = 634732495849521163
        elif payload.emoji.name == ":x:":
            role_to_add = 634732552342601740

        user_id = payload.user_id
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(user_id)

        await member.add_roles(role_to_add)
```

Here is the entier error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AUBIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:/Dossiers AUBIN/Programmation/Python/Mes projets/Graven_Discord.py-master/Commandes/ReactionRole.py", line 26, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await member.add_roles(role_to_add)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'role_to_add' referenced before assignment
```

How I can fix that ?

Comment: If `payload.emoji.name` is none of the two values you test for, `role_to_add` won't be defined.

Comment: you need the else:

Comment: Ok, I will try this